# P5js lags when changing components (with React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

The first time the p5js scripts run correctly and do not stutter, this happens with any drawn animations (even without numerous loops in the draw() function).

When I go to a subpage using `Link to with pathname: "/subpage"`, then I return to the start using `Link to with pathname: "/"`, then the animation on the main page starts lagging (the lagging effect increases with each such transition)

*index.html* file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

How I add p5js to React:

```
import { ReactP5Wrapper } from "react-p5-wrapper";
import sketchDefault from './../sketch/sketchDefault';
...
<ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketchDefault} className="sketchDefault"/>
```

Example p5js animation:

```
function sketch(p5) {
  let font
  let fSize // font size
  let msg // text to write
  let pts = [] // store path data

  let speed = 2;

  let ptBefore = {x:0, y:0}
  let i = 0

  let donePts = []

  var r
  var angle 
  var step
  let circlePoints = []

  p5.preload = () => {
    font = p5.loadFont('./NothingYouCouldDo-Regular.ttf')
  }

  p5.setup = () => {
    p5.createCanvas(100, 100)
    
    p5.frameRate(60)

    fSize = 40
    p5.textFont(font)
    p5.textSize(fSize)
    msg = 'AS'
    pts = font.textToPoints(msg, 0, 0, fSize, {
        sampleFactor: 0.8, // increase for more points
        simplifyThreshold: 0.0 // increase to remove collinear points
    })
    p5.reverse(pts);
    
    //create circle
    r = 40;
    angle = -32*p5.TWO_PI/180;
    step = p5.TWO_PI/180;

    for(let p=0; p<180; p++) {
      var x = r * p5.sin(angle);
      var y = r * p5.cos(angle);
      circlePoints.push({x: x, y: y})
      angle = angle + step;
    }

    p5.stroke(30, 185, 114)
    p5.strokeWeight(3);
    p5.background(19, 30, 42)
  };

  var t = 1;
  p5.draw = () => {
    if(t>=180) {
      p5.noLoop();
    } else {
      p5.translate(p5.width/2, p5.height/2);
      if(i>=pts.length) {
        for(let k=0; k<=speed+2; k++) {
          if(t<180) {
            const p_c = circlePoints[t]
            p5.point(p_c.x, p_c.y);
            t++;
          }
        }
      }
  
      p5.translate(-32, 12);
      for(let k=0; k<=speed+1; k++) {
        if(i>=pts.length) {
          break;
        }
        const p = pts[i]
        if(ptBefore.x != 0) {
          p5.point(p.x, p.y);
          p5.point(ptBefore.x, ptBefore.y);
        }
        ptBefore = pts[i]
        i++
      }
    }
  };
};

export default sketch;
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a solution to my problem anywhere else. I thought old scripts were running all the time in the background, but deleting items containing scripts doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't really an answer, however I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is a minimal example of your ReactJS component hosted in a way where it can be removed and recreated an arbitrary number of times. I don't see any lag here whatsoever. Please update your question to include an actual minimal reproducible example.

```js
function sketchDefault(p5) {
  let font
  let fSize // font size
  let msg // text to write
  let pts = [] // store path data

  let speed = 2;

  let ptBefore = {x:0, y:0}
  let i = 0

  let donePts = []

  var r
  var angle 
  var step
  let circlePoints = []

  p5.preload = () => {
    font = p5.loadFont('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Arial.otf')
  }

  p5.setup = () => {
    p5.createCanvas(100, 100)
    
    p5.frameRate(60)

    fSize = 40
    p5.textFont(font)
    p5.textSize(fSize)
    msg = 'AS'
    pts = font.textToPoints(msg, 0, 0, fSize, {
        sampleFactor: 0.8, // increase for more points
        simplifyThreshold: 0.0 // increase to remove collinear points
    })
    p5.reverse(pts);
    
    //create circle
    r = 40;
    angle = -32*p5.TWO_PI/180;
    step = p5.TWO_PI/180;

    for(let p=0; p<180; p++) {
      var x = r * p5.sin(angle);
      var y = r * p5.cos(angle);
      circlePoints.push({x: x, y: y})
      angle = angle + step;
    }

    p5.stroke(30, 185, 114)
    p5.strokeWeight(3);
    p5.background(19, 30, 42)
  };

  var t = 1;
  p5.draw = () => {
    if(t>=180) {
      p5.noLoop();
    } else {
      p5.translate(p5.width/2, p5.height/2);
      if(i>=pts.length) {
        for(let k=0; k<=speed+2; k++) {
          if(t<180) {
            const p_c = circlePoints[t]
            p5.point(p_c.x, p_c.y);
            t++;
          }
        }
      }
  
      p5.translate(-32, 12);
      for(let k=0; k<=speed+1; k++) {
        if(i>=pts.length) {
          break;
        }
        const p = pts[i]
        if(ptBefore.x != 0) {
          p5.point(p.x, p.y);
          p5.point(ptBefore.x, ptBefore.y);
        }
        ptBefore = pts[i]
        i++
      }
    }
  };
};

const { useState } = React;

function ToggleComponent(props) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  function toggle() {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }
  
  return <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {(counter % 2 === 0) && 
    <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketchDefault} className="sketchDefault"/>}
      </td>
      <td>
        {(counter % 2 === 1) && 
    <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketchDefault} className="sketchDefault"/>}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="2">
        <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
}

(function declareReactP5Wrapper(exports) {
  /* Inlined react-p5-wrapper
    Copyright 2016 James Robb

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
    */
  const { createRef, FC, memo, useState, useLayoutEffect } = React;

  function createCanvas(sketch, wrapper) {
    return new p5(sketch, wrapper);
  }

  const ReactP5WrapperComponent = ({
    sketch,
    children,
    ...props
  }) => {
    const wrapperRef = createRef();
    const [instance, setInstance] = useState();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      if (wrapperRef.current === null) {
        return;
      }

      if (instance) instance.remove();
      const canvas = createCanvas(sketch, wrapperRef.current);
      setInstance(canvas);
    }, [sketch]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      if (instance && instance.updateWithProps) instance.updateWithProps(props);
    }, [props, instance]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => () => instance && instance.remove(), []);

    return <div ref={wrapperRef}>{children}</div>;
  };

  function propsAreEqual(previous, next) {
    const differences = diff(previous, next);

    return differences.length === 0;
  }

  /* microdiff inlined
    MIT License

    Copyright (c) 2021 AsyncBanana

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
    copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
    SOFTWARE.
  */
  const richTypes = { Date: true, RegExp: true, String: true, Number: true };
  function diff(
    obj,
    newObj,
    options = { cyclesFix: true },
    _stack = []
  ) {
    let diffs = [];
    const isObjArray = Array.isArray(obj);
    for (const key in obj) {
      const objKey = obj[key];
      const path = isObjArray ? +key : key;
      if (!(key in newObj)) {
        diffs.push({
          type: "REMOVE",
          path: [path],
          oldValue: obj[key],
        });
        continue;
      }
      const newObjKey = newObj[key];
      const areObjects =
        typeof objKey === "object" && typeof newObjKey === "object";
      if (
        objKey &&
        newObjKey &&
        areObjects &&
        !richTypes[Object.getPrototypeOf(objKey).constructor.name] &&
        (options.cyclesFix ? !_stack.includes(objKey) : true)
      ) {
        const nestedDiffs = diff(
          objKey,
          newObjKey,
          options,
          options.cyclesFix ? _stack.concat([objKey]) : []
        );
        diffs.push.apply(
          diffs,
          nestedDiffs.map((difference) => {
            difference.path.unshift(path);
            return difference;
          })
        );
      } else if (
        objKey !== newObjKey &&
        !(
          areObjects &&
          (isNaN(objKey)
            ? objKey + "" === newObjKey + ""
            : +objKey === +newObjKey)
        )
      ) {
        diffs.push({
          path: [path],
          type: "CHANGE",
          value: newObjKey,
          oldValue: objKey,
        });
      }
    }
    const isNewObjArray = Array.isArray(newObj);
    for (const key in newObj) {
      if (!(key in obj)) {
        diffs.push({
          type: "CREATE",
          path: [isNewObjArray ? +key : key],
          value: newObj[key],
        });
      }
    }
    return diffs;
  }

  exports.ReactP5Wrapper = memo(ReactP5WrapperComponent, propsAreEqual);


})(window);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ToggleComponent />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 100px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

*Note: as you can see it is a bit tricky to make this sample run in a Stack Snippet (**mostly because the folks at @StackOverflow haven't updated the versions of ReactJS and Babel that they support lately** ), however it is clearly possible. It is always best with JavaScript questions if you can include your minimal reproducible example as a runnable Stack Snippet.*